# Dynamically create host wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 3 projects.
ServHost
ServManager
ServClient

My intention is to use send data from client to ServManager and let ServManager dynamically create host endpoints. And, then consuming the Host endpoints using ChannelFactory created at ServManager.

ServHost.cs has the following method:

```
    public void createWorkerHost(Uri addr, RequiredClass workerObj)
    {
        ServiceHost host;
        host = new ServiceHost(workerObj, addr);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRequiredClass), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        host.Open();
    }
```

ServManager.cs has the following methods:

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
            mChannelFactories = new ChannelFactory<IRequiredClass>[0];
            RequiredClass rqObj = new RequiredClass(var1 obj); 
            var endpointAddress = CreateEndPointAddress(1);
            WorkerHost.WorkerHost.createWorkerHost(new Uri(endpointAddress),rqObj);
            mChannelFactories[0] = CreateChannelFactory(endpointAddress);        
    }


    public static ChannelFactory<IRequiredClass> CreateChannelFactory(string address)
    {
        try
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress endpointAddrress = new EndpointAddress(address);
            var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IRequiredClass>(binding, endpointAddrress);                
            return myChannelFactory;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Here, I am able to call ServManager and get data from ServClient over there. After I call the createWorkerHost method, and create the ChannelFactory, when I am trying to execute the exposed method in IRequiredClass using the channel from ChannelFactory, I am getting a TimeoutException.

Its because, the endpoint url keeps on loading until the whole project is debugged. How can I have the url to be loaded without having the whole project debugged.

Comment: The client has a reference to IRequiredClass.. And knows the address.. So why do you have to create the ChannelFactory at the service and return in to the client?

Comment: The client doesn't have a reference to IRequiredClass. It has a reference only to ServManager.cs